# Selenium script disappear after converting Java to Maven project

Tags: java, maven

My Framework stored in a server, there are two workspaces. I was working on my workspace and my framework I won't use Maven. Yesterday, I tried to convert into Maven project. Right clicked on project and choose to convert to maven project. Here happened,  No pom.xml file created and showing error, furthermore, the scripts of the framework disappear and copied the packages from 2nd workspace, workspace2. In case of this critical situation how can I get back my workspace and script as was it is Java Project? Please help me ..